# i can not understand how this is working x => x.Id == _purchase.Centre.Id?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I can not understand the following line: `x => x.Id == _purchase.Centre.Id`

the code is here:

```
private void LoadCentreOptions()
{
    MaterialCentreDataSource mcds = new MaterialCentreDataSource();
    List<MaterialCentre> centres = mcds.GetAll() as List<MaterialCentre>;

    _blankCentre = new MaterialCentre()
    {
        Name = Strings.JournalViewModel_CreditedPartyOption_NotSpecified
    };

    centres.Insert(0, _blankCentre);
    _centreOptions = new ReadOnlyCollection<MaterialCentre>(centres);

    if (_purchase.Centre == null)
        _purchase.Centre = _blankCentre;
    else
        _purchase.Centre = _centreOptions.First(x => x.Id == _purchase.Centre.Id);
}
```

here at the debugging time i am watching that X.Id is incremented .How it is possible?

Comment: Read up on lambda functions in c# then. Way too big a topic for a Stackoverflow question. Voting to close.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson he didn't ask "explain all lambda to me" he simply asked about a line.. and the guys already answered him simple yet good answers...

Comment: And both of those explain this Lambda, and if he knew lambdas he wouldn't need this one explaining which is about as simple as it gets. I know the first time I saw them my eyes started bleeding as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The api `First` is enumerating over the collection and applying the condition to check which one matches and then returns the first match.. So effectively the code translates to

```
foreach(var centreOption in _centreOptions)
{
    if(centreOption.Id==_purchase.Centre.Id)
        return centreOption;
}
```

and if you understand LINQ its basically short for

```
_centreOptions.Where(x => x.Id == _purchase.Centre.Id).First();
```

To understand the exact implementation of First read [Jon Skeets blogpost](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/29/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-11-first-single-last-and-the-ordefault-versions.aspx).

Comment: The the page on the link provided is not available anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This line runs for every element in the `_centreOptions` Enumerable:

```
_purchase.Centre = _centreOptions.First(x => x.Id == _purchase.Centre.Id);
```

And checking if the `Id` of object equals to `_purchase.Centre.Id`.
It will return the first element that satisfy the condition.

So you see two `id` in two iterations.